# Expected execution behaviour of jetty ContainerLifecycleListener with Priority annotation?

Tags: java, jetty, jax-rs

I created a number of classes that implement ContainerLifecycleListener and registered them in my Application class with a Priority annotation.

Is it expected that tasks start according to the priorities assigned when jetty starts?

Thanks.

Please see code below:

```
@Priority(TaskPri.NORMAL)
public class Task1 implements ContainerLifecycleListener {
....
}



@Priority(TaskPri.LOW)
public class Task2 implements ContainerLifecycleListener {
...
}


public class TaskPri {
    public static final int NORMAL = 6500;
    public static final int LOW = 6000;
}


public class App extends ResourceConfig {
      public App() {
 packages("com.example.tasks").register(Task1.class).register(Task2.class);
     }
 }
```

There is an option to register the classes with bindingPriority, cannot find what it exactly means, any ideas ?

Comment: Might want to indicate which `ContainerLifecycleListener` you are attempting to setup.  There are many different kinds, provide by many different libraries/packages.

Comment: I am talking about ContainerLifecycleListener in package org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi .